# eclipse mylyn with redmine

Tags: java, eclipse, redmine, mylyn

Is it possible to connect mylyn to redmine without rest support in redmine?

Comment: Google is your friend. http://bit.ly/n7FvJP

Comment: Heh, I was there. The connector I found requires plugin to be installed in redmine to facilitate mylyn integration with it. Also I found mentions about generic web connector but I could not find alive link to it.

Comment: You can find more information in the mylyn manual at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn_User_Guide#Generic_Web_Templates_Connector.

Comment: Just to know, why not settle for rest connection?

Comment: @luca-geretti I don't have access to redmine to setup rest plugin there. That is the only reason.

Comment: Yes it is, I found a nice tutorial at http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Mylyn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- there is a link http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/incubator/3.8 that can be used in Eclipse.  for Eclipse indigo :

  - Help -> Install New Software -> Add -> use the link above for URL
  - there should be plugin to check off : Mylyn Incubator -> Mylyn Task Connector:Web Templates (Advanced)(Incubation).  Version  = 3.8.0.I20120414-0402
- after installing it, i was able to follow steps outlined in http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Mylyn ( the section 'Using the generic web repository connector' ).
- there is also a half decent [video on Youtube](http://youtube.com/watch?v=il7L0ZH25ME)  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse indigo then use the update site:

(As of 09/16/2012)
http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/incubator/3.8

install "Mylyn Tasks Connector: Web Templates (Advanced)" and follow the instructions at the link mikalv posted above.

It looks like the incubator links is changing as Eclipse versions go up. It looks like the best way to find out the update url is to check [Generic Web Templates Connector section of Mylyn User Guide wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn_User_Guide#Generic_Web_Templates_Connector) They provide the up to date link to *mylyn download site* where you can find the *update url for the incubator*.