# How to connect from Mylyn to Redmine?

Tags: eclipse, redmine, mylyn

How to connect from Mylyn to Redmine?

Are there any connectors?

This site pretends to have one https://github.com/danmunn/redmine_mylyn_connector

but contains only instruction to install something on server side. How eclipse can know there is some server?

**UPDATE**

Plugin from here [Mylyn & Redmine Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498426/mylyn-redmine-integration) is not working, saying "error 404".

Comment: Related: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7506357/1639625), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/498426/1639625), and all of [those](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mylyn+redmine).

Comment: @tobias_k everything looks old and dormant. I need to know modern confirmed working solution

Comment: I used one of those to connect my Mylyn to Redmine, and it worked. Can't tell you more, unfortunately, since I then decided that I actually liked the web interface better and stopped using it. (I think I used this [HowTo](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Mylyn))